# Can $\Gamma^\perp \subseteq \Gamma$, with $\Gamma$ bing some space, happen?

Tags: vector-spaces, orthogonality

I read on a book a condition $\Gamma^\perp \subseteq \Gamma$ and I'm struggling to understand its meaning. Is it possible to satisfy such condition for a given space $\Gamma$?

EDIT: I'm studying linear codes for error correction, so in my case the space is $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{F}^n_2$, which is simply a binary vector of $n$ elements.

Comment: I don’t know much but I believe it can happen in Lorentzian geometry

Comment: Hint: there's such a set $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{F}_2^3$ with $|\Gamma| = 4$ and $\Gamma^\perp = \Gamma$. And if $a \in \Gamma$, then $a \cdot a$...?

Comment: {001,010,100,111}?